# SwiftUI: How can I send push Notification when the JSON file receives new entries from the backend?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I´m new in SwiftUI. How can I trigger a notification if a new entry is available from the backend using a JSON file. The app should also constantly send new queries to the backend and check whether there is new information. If there is new information, a notification should be sent to the user. An example would be WhatsApp / Email of how it works. The app is not in the App Store for now. So it cannot run through the Apple servers.

Comment: This may depend on the backend you are using. which one is it?

Comment: @JVS Ah okay. The backend is not yet available but will be developed "in-house".I thought there was "a standard code" for sending notifications and for making constant requests to a backend and then I would have to e.g. just change the server address.

Comment: The general idea would be to have a server-side (backend) function that sends out a notification to your application saying that something has been updated/edited/deleted and your app on the other side subscribes to that specific type of notification and handles this after receivement